# Generate an arrow back within a circle using Image Asset (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, vector, android-drawable

I want to use the next image in my ActionBar:
[image]

I can put the image in my `drawable` folder and use it without problems.

But I want to use this image with different sizes (`mdpi`, `hdpi`, etc).

So I am trying to generate a different sizes versions of this image using the `Image Asset` in Android Studio.

The generator works great if the `Icon Type` is `Launcher Icons`, but the output is a `mipmap` (a launcher icon for the app).

[image]

If I select the right `Icon Type` the output targets the `drawable` folder, but unfortunately the icons generated are just a circles.

[image]

---

I guess that Android Studio is telling me that I have to use vectors instead of images for the icons that will be used in the ActionBar. Is it right?

So I have selected a predefined icon from the `Clip Arts`:

[image]

But there is no a `Shape` option for `Action Bar and Tab Icons`.
That would be great, but it is only available for `Launcher Icons`.

Finally my question can be summarized in:

1. There is a way to generate a `back arrow` with a `circle shape` using the `Image Asset` tool in Android Studio?
2. I guess that I can use the arrow icon and additionally apply a `drawable resource` to get a circle button. But in performance, **1 vector + 1 drawable resource is better than 1 image with different resolutions?**

Thank you in advance.

Please give me some ideas to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Image Asset` doesn't provide setting background for normal icons. There are multiple solutions to this problem, the easiest one is go [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-app-shortcut.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=arrow_back&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_shortcut_arrow_back&foreColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(245%2C%20245%2C%20245)), find your desired icon. This will generate all different sizes.

Moreover, you can make image using Photoshop and generate its icons from [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I upload the image to the 2nd link, the output is just a circle. But the 1st link works great. It says "Generate app launcher shortcut icons (Android 7.1+)." but I guess that I can use the generated images as regular drawable resources.

Comment: Yes, the sizes are all same. For the second one, you have to make any size icon in Photoshop which you want, and then make it's `drawables` icon from there. And if this answer helped you, it's nice gesture to accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but the ```Action Bar and Tab Icon Generator``` works exactly as the ```Image Asset``` in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Just to solve your issue. Please have a look at this [CircularContactView](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=ListViewVariants-master/app/src/main/java/lb/listviewvariants/utils/CircularContactView.java) link.
You can generate the back arrow from the resource as drawable, and then you can use the instance of the above CircularContactView class to fit the arrow inside it.

Something like this:

`circularContactViewObj.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_back_arrow, Color.YOUR_COLOR);`

Answer (score 0):

you also use vector image like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">

<path
    android:fillColor="#28274b"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M21.49 12.28C21.49 17.58 17.22 21.89 11.96 21.89C6.7 21.89 2.43 17.58 2.43 12.28C2.43 6.98 6.7 2.68 11.96 2.68C17.22 2.68 21.49 6.98 21.49 12.28Z" />
<!--<path
    android:fillColor="#ffffff"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M12.1 7.19L5.72 11.99L12.1 16.8L12.1 13.75L18.87 13.75L18.87 10.23L12.1 10.23L12.1 7.19Z" />-->
<path android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z"/>
```